# Is it possible to pay directly to a credit card using PHP?

Tags: api, paypal, sdk, payment, credit-card

Is it possible to pay to a customers credit card directly either using authorise.net or any other means. Kindly let me know if there is any API in PHP that can be used to pay to a credit card.

I am not charging to the credit card. In fact I want to return amount to a credit card. I saw authorise.net SDK but could not find any reverse API i.e to pay directly to a credit card.

Comment: You don't pay to a credit card. You "refund" to them and, as the name implies, you can only return money previously charged. You cannot use these services to put money on to a credit card.

Comment: You tagged the question with PayPal... Doesn't PayPal encapsulate the details of the credit card behind a payment gateway anyway?  Wouldn't you just send the funds to the user through their API and let PayPal handle how/when the funds are distributed to the user's financial account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A credit (refund) does not need to be bound to an existing authorisation & settlement - that's an implementation artifact of most gateway APIs and of the higher level APIs provided by Banks & Clearing houses.

For Authorise.net you may be able to use [*Expanded Credit Capabilities (ECC)*](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A158&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1346038078445).

Another google term would be *Non-referenced refunds*.

You could also attempt to locate a gateway that implemented one of the card scheme APIs designed specifically for Merchant -> Cardholder credits; Visa's is called *Visa Direct*.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I think you wont be able to do it. using authorize.Net you can register your bank account and money can be credited to your account but not to Credit card. Authorise.NET gateway enables Internet merchants to accept online payments via credit card and debit card.